# Angular.js adding values to an modelarray with ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and still learning. I read alot about generating static HTML with a CMS but then transform this into Angular Models/Scopes to then process it further and further.

Now I'm trying to add values to a array of a model in the ng-init directive like this:

```
<div ng-init="art[0].anzahl=3">...</div>
<div ng-init="art[1].anzahl=2">...</div>
<div ng-init="art[2].anzahl=9">...</div>
```

But it won't work, does anyone can see my dumb mistake or am I totaly wrong about how I use ng-init?

Here's the link to the complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/Preexo/xVUty/

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make sure your `art` array is declared first (uncommenting out your commented code) before you try and set default values using `ngInit`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVUty/2/) as an example.

```
$scope.art = [
    {'anzahl': 0},
    {'anzahl': 0},
    {'anzahl': 0}        
];

$scope.addOne = function(artIndex) {
    $scope.art[artIndex].anzahl += 1;
}
```

**Update: here are some other options**

1) In case this helps at all with your understanding you can use an `ng-repeat` and declare default values in your controller code for `anzahl` like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzDjr/). This will reduce the code in the markup and move the declaration of the model into the controller which can be cleaner depending on what you're going for.

2) If you still wanted to use `ngInit` you can push each item into the `art` array in your markup like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAj3q/).

Comment: about your update: I get your point, but I'm generating the HTML with a CMS and i would be hard to generate just the javascript-array... but thanks alot though!